# Bootstrap: hide glyphicon-time from datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

in my Cakephp app, I use [Bootstrap Datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to select dates.

I did not find in documentation how to hide the time glyphicon
[image: screenshot]

[image]

in the appView initialize(), I used this:

```
public function initialize()
{
    .....

    $this->Form->addWidget('datetime', ['DateTimePicker']);
    $this->Form->addWidget('date', ['DatePicker']);
}
```

in add.ctp:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"><?= $this->Form->input('purchase_date') ?></div>
        </div>
```

any help please?

Comment: Add the HTML code related with the calendar or inspect the calendar and put down the code so that we can help you with it.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: in

> webroot\js\bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

I removed this code:

```
<li class="picker-switch accordion-toggle"><a class="btn" style="width:100%"><span class="'+i.options.icons.time+'"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set "format" property to "L" during initialization:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ format : 'L'});
```

Comment: thanks Andrey. in which file exactly should I initilize it ? (I updated my question including more details)

Comment: How do you add DateTimePicker to "purchase_date"?

Comment: in assets Entity, I declared this: `* @property \Cake\I18n\Time $purchase_date`

Comment: in assets table, I use this:  `       $validator
            ->date('purchase_date', ['mdy'])
            ->allowEmpty('purchase_date');`

Comment: Do you use javascript activate widget for that input field?

Comment: if you go  to options, first option "format" let you setup date and time format and by extensiont to remove time part from witget http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Comment: I saw this documentation. I don't find it in my cakephp code. this is the code I use for it: 
`class DateTimePickerWidget extends BasicWidget
{

    public function render(array $data, ContextInterface $context)
    {
        .....
        $data['append'] = $this->_templates->format('inputGroupAddon', ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar']);

        if (is_object($data['val']) && get_class($data['val']) == 'DateTime') {
            $data['val'] = null;
        }

        return parent::render($data, $context);
    }
}`

Comment: sorry, I'm still confused. I did not find where to put the code you've mentioned in my cakephp code.

Comment: should I add "cakephp" as a TAG for this question, since it seems to be a specific issue in cakephp ?

Comment: Sorry based on your code snippets I don't see there DateTimePicker is initialized. Code should go in script tags in html inside document ready event function.

Comment: Do you have any references to DateTimePicker in your javascript?

Comment: I don't find anything. In my "View/Widget' folder, I have 2 files: DatePickerWidget.php and DateTimePickerWidget.php in which we use BootstrapUI\View\Widget\BasicWidget;

Comment: To change behavior of picker to use only date you have to set format, but I'm not familiar with CakePHP and cannot really help you here. Maybe one those php file have reference to datetimepicker.